# Simple Outlook 2010 add-in

Tags: .net, outlook, outlook-addin

I want to create Add-in for outlook 2010, that will open TFS work items link directly in Visual Studio Team Explorer...but I can't find enough information on how to accomplish this relatively simple task.

Currently I found how to create a simple Outlook 2010 add-in and how to connect to "NewMail Inspector". But how I can force the links to our TFS server to open in Visual Studio and not in browser?

I thought just to catch click event on link inside mail and check if it's authority points to TFS, but it looks like it's impossible to catch click event.

Then I thought that I can parse incoming/existing mails and replace link with my custom URI scheme, then to use simple CMD application to open the VS, but I can't find how to parse currently active mail...the active mail can be in preview pane or mail can be opened...

Does anybody have ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TFS, but it sounds like you can handle that part already. Presumably there's some sort of command line option that will work there. It sounds like the problem is detecting the link, and triggering your code in the first place.

The active item selected in an explorer (the main window of Outlook) is available from the [Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861267%28v=office.14%29.aspx) attribute of the Explorer. You can grab Explorer events in essentially the same way as Inspectors-the one you want is SelectionChange. For Inspectors, you can get at the current item from Inspector.[CurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869722%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Once you have the item, check if it's a MailItem, cast and work with the Body property.

You could also add a button to the inspector/explorer's ribbon, and use that rather than altering the messages themselves. On click, examine the item's body for links of the expected form, and run your code then. There's information about creating and working with ribbons [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386097.aspx).